# How to test whether GET requests works in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, flask, get

How do I test different routes in Python Flask?

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/test1', methods=['GET'])
def firstTest():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "First test passed"

@app.route('/test2', methods=['GET'])
def secondTest():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "Second test passed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am trying to understand how to test routes /test1 and /test2 to make sure the GET method works properly. How do I send those routes a dummy GET request for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by several ways:

1. From your browser in your local machine just go to `http://localhost:5000/your_route_name`

in your case:

for test1:

```
http://localhost:5000/test1  # 5000 is default port
```

for test2:

```
http://localhost:5000/test2
```

2. using curl from terminal

   curl http://localhost:5000/test1

   curl http://localhost:5000/test2

you can test from postman too.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a view function will have both GET and POST methods, as the successful submission of a form using POST will then GET something from the server for the client.

if visiting 'http://localhost:5000/' after your app is running returns anything, then you can be sure that your GET or POST methods will be working fine.

Let us know if your seeing the 'test passed' statements when you visit those urls.